# What is the difference between making several simple subscriptions and a single complex one?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Is there any practical difference between keeping several simple (plain) subscriptions and keeping a single complex (many levels) one? (with publish-composite, for example)

Seems to me that there shouldn't be any difference, but I wanted to be sure. I prefer sticking to plain subs as it seems to make the code clearer in highly modular projects, but only if that wouldn't bring any performance or scalability issues.

So, can someone help me?

Comment: doesn't that entirely on the amounts of data you would have to send? If you join server side, then the data set to sync can be very small. Just what you need. If you need to sync several collections first before deciding on the client that you only need a small sliver of it, then you are sending more than necessary which can impact performance. But again, that may not always be the case.

Answer (score 0):

There are two key differences in doing several plain subscriptions vs. keeping complex composite subscription

**1) Exposure/Privacy**

A composite subscription allows you to perform joins/filters on the server side to ensure that you only send data that the current user has authority to see. You don't want to expose your entire database to the client. Keep in mind that even if your UI is not showing the data, the user can go into the console and grab all the data that your server publishes.

**2) Client performance**

Performing joins/filters on the client can be expensive if you have a large dataset. This is of course dependent on your application. Additionally, if the database is constantly being updated, and those updates should not be visible to the user; you will constantly need to transfer the updates to the client without deriving benefits from the network expense.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question can't be given a precise answer without more details specific to your application. That being said, I think it's an important question so I'll outline of some things to consider.

To be clear, the focus of this answer will be debating the relative merits of server-side and client-side [reactive joins](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactive-joins-in-meteor/).

**decide if you need reactivity**

You can produce a simple join of multiple collections without any reactivity in the publisher (see the first example from the article above). Depending on the nature of the problem, it may be that you don't really need a reactive join. Imagine you are joining comments and authors, but your app always has all of the possible authors published already. In that case the fundamental flaw in non-reactive joins (missing child documents after a new parent) won't exist, so a reactive publication is redundant.

**consider your security model**

As I mention in my article on [template joins](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/template-joins), server-side joins have the advantage of bundling all of your data together, whereas client-joins require more granular publishers. Consider the security implications of having a publisher like `commentsAndAuthors` vs two generic implementations of `comments` and `users`. The latter suggests that anyone could request an array of user documents without context.

**server joins can be CPU and memory hogs**

Look carefully at the implementation of the library you are considering for your server-side joins. Some of them use [observe](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe) which requires that each complete document in the dependency chain be kept in memory. Others are implemented only on [observeChanges](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe_changes) which is more efficient but makes packages a bit less flexible in what they can do.

**look for observer reuse**

One of your goals should be to [reuse your observers](https://kadira.io/academy/improve-cpu-and-network-usage/). In other words, given that you will have S concurrent subscriptions you will only end up doing ~(S-I) work where I is the number of identical observers across clients. Depending on the nature of your subscriptions, you may see greater observer reuse with more granular subscriptions, but this is very application specific.

**beware of latency**

A big advantage of server-side joins is that they deliver all of the documents effectively at once. Compare that to a client join which must wait for each set of parent documents to arrive before activating the child subscriptions. A N-level client-join would have N round-trips before the initial set of documents will be delivered to the client.

**conclusion**

You'll need to take all of the above into consideration when deciding which technique to use for each of your publications. The reality is that benchmarking a live app on something like [kadira](https://kadira.io/) is the only way to arrive at a conclusive answer.

Comment: that is really helpful, thanks. I will probably try the more granular thing. I'm just worried that having a lot (10+) little subscriptions is inherently worse than having a single chunky one. Don't know enough about publish/sub implementation to know.